# I need to execute particular transaction every 2 mins interval for 1 hour duration load test in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Transaction details
Launch login are kept inside of once only controller

Need to do 5 to 8 transaction every 2 mins interval

1.Launch
2.Login
3.Click product
4.Click item
5.Create order item(need to run every 2 min interval

6.Fil details save(need to run every 2 min interval)

7.Order history(need to run every 2 min interval

8.view order(need to run every 2 min interval)

Could you please tell me how to do that for 1 hour duration test...

Answer (score 0):

Normally people use [JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer) for creating delays between requests.

Timers are being executed before each Sampler it their [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so if you arrange you put [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) at the same level as your 6-8 samplers it will create a 2 minutes delay before each of them

[image]

Alternatively you can use [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) which creates a delay exactly where it's placed